# How to write the word 'smart phone' in a research article?

Tags: expressions

1. Smart phone
2. Smartphone
3. Smart-phone

I am really looking for some help regarding hyphen (-) issue in text found in research article. Is there any standard method how to use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a good question for referring to the Google Ngram Viewer, to see which is most popular lately.

If you look [here](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=smart%20phone%2Csmart-phone%2Csmartphone&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1990&year_end=2015&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Csmart%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bsmart%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmart%20Phone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmart%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Csmart%20-%20phone%3B%2Cc0%3B.t4%3B%2Csmartphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3BSmartphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bsmartphone%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BSmartPhone%3B%2Cc0):

[image]

You see that since 2000, **smartphone** has increasingly surpassed **smart phone**, with **smart-phone** virtually nonexistent.

Comment: +1, Is it possible for you to kindly provide some related help on hyphen issues?

Comment: @Mithun - Welcome to stack exchange. Note that if you wish to award +1 to an answer you should click the large up-arrow symbol at its top left.

Comment: @chasly from UK Thank you. I already did, however, as per my previous experience in SE, I think I require 15 reputation to show my upvote publicly.

Comment: @Okay - no problem. I'll delete my comment shortly.

Comment: As for help on hyphens, there are scores, if not hundreds of questions on this forum about hyphens.  Unfortunately, views differ, so you may have to refer to your textbook or favorite wring/grammar site, as well as paying attention to how and when other people hyphenate. Hyphenation changes over time; separate words become joined with hyphens, and some then fuse into a single word. How long this takes, and whether it happens at all for a given word pair, are rather unpredictable.

Comment: Oh, and thanks to whoever embedded the ngram graph for me.